# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Refused connection to database - Laravel

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds

I am hosting my Laraval website in AWS using elastic beanstalk, it was working properly till tomorrow but when I visited my site today it showed the error " Connection Refused with database ", I checked my RDS instance and it was live and working properly. 
I solved this by accessing my ec2-instace and clearing config and cache, and then rebuilt the cache. I used following commands in the same order.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

My site is again live now but I want to ask why it went down? I didnt change anything since weeks so that was not from my side. Can any one help me with this? Thanks

Comment: Maybe Autoscaling group had to terminate it and start new one? And something went wrong when deploying your app again?

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the comments. I have just one instance, and AWS didnt initiate new instances. I uploaded my app last month and didnt change anything till now, it was working fine. it suddenly showed this behavior today.